# Angular 6 BehaviorSubject 'undefined': Error: TypeError: Cannot read property of my declared BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, rxjs, spring-websocket, behaviorsubject

I'm pretty new to Angular (as well as StackOverflow) and I've been trying to make a small project using Spring Boot as my back-end and WebSockets in attempt to make a small real-time web application (all these technologies are fairly new to me and I'm eager to learn them!). The problem I'm having is the use of BehaviorSubjects. I intend to use my BehaviorSubject ('messageSubject$') each time I receive a message from Spring Boot through a WebSocket. Basically once I receive a message I would just have my BehaviorSubject pick up on it by using the 'next()' method and then have one of my components subscribe to it (The subscription to my web socket and definition of my BehaviorSubject are all within a service). However when I do this I get an error displayed on Google Chrome's console: 'Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'messageSubject$' of undefined'. I'm very confused as to why such an error would pop-up since I did make sure to define it correctly (I've watched multiple tutorials and they each seem to do it the same way).

Here is how I imported BehaviorSubject from rxjs:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/internal/BehaviorSubject';
```

Here is the BehaviorSubject definition (on top of the constructor):

```
private messageSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('default message');
```

Here is the subscription to my WebSocket and where I try to use my Behavior Subject:

```
    // Connecting to WebSocket found in Spring Boot MS. Also checkout polyfill.ts
  connect(user: string, password: string) {
    console.log('Inside Connect. Guest and Password: ' + user + ' ' + password);
    const socket = new SockJs('http://localhost:8080/football-ws');
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    this.stompClient.connect(user, password, this.onConnected);
    console.log('Attempting to connect!');
  }

  onConnected = (frame: any) => {
    console.log('Frame: ' + frame);
    this.stompClient.subscribe('/topic/public', this.onMessageReceived);
  }


  onMessageReceived(message: any) {
    console.log('Message Received from MS: '  +  message);
    try {
      this.messageSubject$.next(message.body);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Error: ' + e);
    }
  }

  getMessageSubject() {
    return this.messageSubject$.asObservable();
  }
```

I apologize if a question like this has been asked before, I did research a lot about my problem here however none of the changes the solutions suggested seem to work. Thank you all so much for your help, if any more code snippets or information is needed I'd be happy to provide them to you!

Comment: You're looking at the wrong part of the code. "Cannot read property 'messageSubject$' of undefined" means that the instance of your service is undefined, not the `messageSubject$` itself -- you still don't have an instance of the class which is supposed to contain `messageSubject$`.

Comment: Try defining `onMessageReceived` with an arrow function, the same way that you defined `onConnected`: `onMessageReceived = (message: any) => { ... }`.

Comment: Oh how so? Would I need to define the service within the app.module.ts? I did list it as a provider there but the problem remained. @LazarLjubenović

Comment: I'll try it, thanks @ConnorsFan

Comment: I don't think that is the problem @LazarLjubenović - it's about "this" scope - see my answer.

Comment: Or you can bind `this`: `this.stompClient.subscribe('/topic/public', this.onMessageReceived.bind(this));`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I defined the onMessageReceived method the way you suggested and the error went away! Thanks for everyones help :) But can you please provide me some insight as to why it worked? What's the major difference on the way I had it and the way you suggested?

Comment: I find remembering to use `.bind(this)` everywhere to be really hard work @ConnorsFan but I guess that would work as well!

Comment: @MichaelValentine see my answer - "this" in javascript does not strongly mean "the current object" like it does in other languages, the arrow-operator makes it work much more like other languages.

Comment: @MarkHughes - I personally don't use the `bind` syntax very much but I am getting used to it, since I mark that question as a duplicate a few times every day. :-)

Comment: I sympathise with people on this one @ConnorsFan - if you don't realise it is to do with "this" scoping (which isn't at all obvious until you know), it's almost impossible to search for the right thing to find the right way to do it!

Comment: @MarkHughes just finished reading your answer thank you so much! I had a feeling it was something small I was messing up on but I never knew that 'this' in javascript doesn't work exactly like in other languages such as C++ and Java. Is there a way I can give both you and ConnorsFan credit?

Comment: @MichaelValentine you can accept or upvote answers as you wish :)

Comment: @MarkHughes - I sympathise with them too. That's why I redirect them to the generic answer given by Felix Kling (and I give them a quick fix in a comment).

Comment: @MarkHughes and ConnorsFan thanks so much guys I was pulling my hairs out because I couldn't find the problem. I literally made a StackOverflow account just for this (no pun intended) because I felt like I was going crazy lol

Comment: @ConnorsFan that is a very good generic answer, I should get in the habit of looking for the good canonical answers rather than leaping into writing half a page myself ;) MichaelValentine glad you got it working - welcome to JS "this" ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem will be caused by the scope of "this" being different in your callbacks. JavaScript has a concept of "this" which is unlike most other languages, however typescript (and modern Javascript) has another syntax to work around this, giving you a more intuitive behavior of "this".

```
this.stompClient.connect(user, password, (frame: any) => this.onConnected(frame));
```

.. and ...

```
this.stompClient.subscribe('/topic/public', (message: any) => this.onMessageReceived(message));
```

This syntax ensures that the value of "this" is as you would expect when you execute the callbacks.

You can also put the callback inline using this syntax, for example:

```
this.stompClient.connect(user, password, (frame: any) => {
    console.log('Frame: ' + frame);
    this.stompClient.subscribe('/topic/public', (message: any) => {
        console.log('Message Received from MS: '  +  message);
        try {
            this.messageSubject$.next(message.body);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Error: ' + e);
        }
    });
});
```